# How can below link SVG polygon animation can be created

Tags: svg, jquery-svg, svg-animate

Would you please tell me how can this http://www.zwei14.de/en/ polygon SVG animation can be created?

Comment: view-source will tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

You can design reasonable SVG in inkscape or adobe Illustrator, the SVG code it kicked out in an xml style.

For animation, you can view the source code and see what the JS files are doing, they appear to be using paper.js which looks like a animation framework for html5 canvas.
http://www.zwei14.de/assets/js/paperjs.vectorMorpher.js?v=2

Read More:
http://paperjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for the response. but he has created a custom made .Js file other than the paperjs.